# Using robots.txt and sitemaps in slim framework app?

Tags: php, seo, slim

I am creating a website using Slim and wanted to do some SEO. The problem is Slim being more of an API based framework does not serve files typically and uses endpoints. How do i serve the `robots.txt` file and other `sitemap.xml` files to be indexed by search engines?

Should i make separate endpoints or use `.htaccess`. If so how do i do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `slim` but creating `robots.txt` manually is simple ! also for google, just define it in `Search Console` Some robots find sitemap in root automatically and no need to define it on robots.txt, but why you don't make it manually..

Comment: The problem is not making the `robots.txt` file it is allowing access to it. Slim redirects all URLs to `index.php` and `index.php` takes care of what action needs to be taken for which URL. Since `robots.txt` is usally hosted on `http://example.com/robots.txt`i asked whether making an URL endpoint for `/robots.txt` is generally the method or is there anything else.

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` file

Comment: Hey here's my `.htaccess`

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

i see 2 ways (without knowning details about Slim)

- Add a depending robots meta element to each outputed HTML resource
- or… add a route, matching all requested robots.txt and output the depending content dynamic

Comment: Oh okie, will try.